# How do I send a user uploaded CSV file to my Rails backend with AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, csv, post

I am running a Rails/React web app and have a file input field for users to upload CSV files. I would like to send this CSV file to my backend, parse through it and use the info to create a new batch of users.

I have my input field

```
<div>
 <label htmlFor="add-doc">Bulk Add</label>
 <input style={{display: 'none'}} onChange={this.uploadCSV} id="add-doc" name='csv-file' type="file"/>
</div>
```

And my onChange function. I have tried a bunch of different things, mostly I think it comes down to how I am passing the file off, it probably is in the wrong format? I dont know

```
uploadCSV(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let file = evt.target.files[0]
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/client/employees',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
   });
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message? The first thing I can think of is security because authenticity_token is missing, if your Rails application is expecting it. I usually do this by having the file input wrapped inside a <form> tag in the HTML code, and submit the form using AJAX. This way your authenticity_token is in the form. If you want to do it your way, you'll have to append authenticity_token to your ajax POST.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the [gem pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for rails? If affirmative put a `binding.pry` on your controller method and write `params` on server terminal and put the answer.

Perhaps can be the encoding from frontend to backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use an enc type `multipart/form-data` because it is a file upload.

I am coming to the conclusion on the fact that you are saying the issue may be in the client side and not the server side. If you can give a specific error using a stack trace or some info from a break point, I can be of help. This is what comes on the top of my head.

```
uploadCSV(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let file = evt.target.files[0]
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

   $.ajax({
       url: '/api/v1/client/employees',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
   });
 });
```